# Goland debug go got hanged. Goland 2021.3

Tags: go, debugging, goland

[IDE screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TryQI.png)

It just hang there like forever.
[Goland version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIW61.png)
And I use Goland 2021.3. According to previous question this bug should hv been fixed in 2021.2 but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Could you please open Terminal (View | Tool Windows | Terminal) and share the output of `go version`? Have you tried to reinstall XCode CLI tools? What macOS version are you using?

Comment: go version go1.17.3 darwin/arm64
macOS monterey 12.0.1

Comment: Haven't tried reinstalling XCode CLI tools, cause I don't know whether it will be helpful.

Comment: Can you run Delve via CLI? Does it work?

Comment: problem solved. Need to manual install delve. 
Follows https://github.com/go-delve/delve/tree/master/Documentation/installation